# 2 Pin Wire Terminal Connector in OrCAD

Tags: orcad

I am searching for 2 Pin Wire terminal connector in orcad. Can anyone suggest me where i can find Wire Terminal Connectors? Under which category in orcad library can i find 2 Pin wire terminal connector. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am searching Green wire terminal connector. Below link shows the connector i am searching for

https://www.google.co.in/search?q=2+pin+wire+terminal+connector+in+orcad&rlz=1C1GIWA_enIN604IN604&espv=2&biw=1365&bih=798&tbm=isch&imgil=BQVllfxS_RBg0M%253A%253BuooKCQ8mlh0ouM%253Bhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Frarecomponents.com%25252Fstore%25252F1219&source=iu&pf=m&fir=BQVllfxS_RBg0M%253A%252CuooKCQ8mlh0ouM%252C_&usg=__Bi9kNsNaThGZIbEohYXu-zs0Fgw%3D&dpr=0.75&ved=0ahUKEwj2mezp0pDOAhUFQY8KHSFJA0UQyjcIRw&ei=pBaXV_a3DIWCvQShko2oBA#imgrc=BQVllfxS_RBg0M%3A

Comment: Wouldn't this simply be a 2-pin connector? In my older versions of OrCad this was called "CON2".

Comment: Try opening the library called connector and typing con2 at the prompt.

Comment: A two pin connector can even be a 2 pin molex connector or 2 pin berg strip connector. How do i differentiate between ordinary 2 pin connector and a wire terminal connector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyways i designed my own 2 Pin wire terminator connector by editing CON2 from Connector library. Better solutions than this are appreciated.

[image: 2 Pin Wire Terminator]

Comment: With ANY CAD system, you will have to make some of your own schematic symbols and PCB footprints, or adapt supplied symbols to suit your needs.

Comment: Thank You Peter. Now I am messing with PCB footprints for my schematic. :)